# What is the equivalent of native:aggregate() in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, aggregation, grouping

I have two layers which I want to connect using the `aggregate()` function with the Field Calculator. I can do this using the processing tool:

```
processing.run("native:aggregate", {
    'INPUT' : 'XX.gpkg|layername=obj_flurname',
    'GROUP_BY' : '"Aufn_Nr"',
    'AGGREGATES': [
        {'aggregate': 'first_value','delimiter': ',','input': '"Aufn_Nr"','length': 50,'name': 'Aufn_Nr','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},
        {'aggregate': 'concatenate_unique','delimiter': ', ','input': '"name"','length': 254,'name': 'name','precision': 0,'sub_type': 10,'type': 11,'type_name': 'stringlist'}],
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    })
```

When I want to implement the same thing in the Field Calculator, I don't have the option to `group_by` like in the `native:aggrregte` function. Is it possible to add this group_by, or do I have to run this with the advanced field calculator (with Python)?

My efforts so far:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='XXX_1da2ccba_0147_4280_a0e9_439870e296c4',
    aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
    expression:="name",
    concatenator:=', '
    )
```

But this only aggregates all possible unique values to all rows. How could I change this so that it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `aggregate()` function, use the [`concatenate_unique()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concatenate-unique) function: there, you have the option to set a `group_by` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this tomorrow. I am happy you answered so fast. I am a Student at UZH :)

Comment: Great! As UZH student, please also notice this: https://www.gis-hub.uzh.ch/

Comment: Oh thats really cool. I did not know this about this hub. I will keep me updated. Ross, your collegue, is my professor at uni :D Thanks for your help & see you

Comment: It worked, thank you!